# Private repo can't read with Git on composer installation on CentOS server

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php, php-deployer

I'm trying to install some private repos via Composer in my Laravel application using deployer, I've created my github SSH alias's and added my keys with `ssh-add -k path-to-key` and have added them to the individual private repos, it seems that the server is still struggling to access these, my repos of my project are included as such:

```json
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@my-alias:company/my-package.git"
    }
]
```

My `config` for Git on my server is...

```
Host my-alias github.com
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/my_package_id_rsa
```

I have multiple hosts in there, the above is just one of 6. The error when `composer install` is attempted through Deployer is...

> ERROR: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>
> and the repository exists.

When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` on the server I get:

> Hi company/my-package! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

So I would've thought the server would be able to read my composer file and clone the repo successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If `ssh -T git@github.com` works on the server, it means the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is working, *not* `/root/.ssh/my_package_id_rsa`

If you want to test access with `/root/.ssh/my_package_id_rsa`, you would need to type:

```
sudo ssh -Tv my-alias
```

"`sudo`" because otherwise `/root/.ssh` would not be accessible anyway.
Which means the ssh config file must be in `/root/.ssh/config`
And the Host entry must be `my-alias`. Not "`my-alias github.com`"

That would also means the `composer install` would have to be executed as `root` (`sudo`), which is not a best practice.